# delayed_job running slow when many workers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, virtual-machine, delayed-job, cpu-usage

Our app has a search task which take <30 sec to run. We moved the task to background using delayed_job, it works great. To handle more search request, we open 60 delayed_job workers, the problem comes when more workers working at the same time.

If I send one request to server, it takes ~30 sec to finish the job; Then I try to send 10 requests to the server, each jobs take >3 mins to finish... And if I try to send 30 request to the server at the same time, each jobs take 26 mins to finish..........my god...

Our search task can split into 2 part. First, sending out 10-20 API requests to 3rd party server using threading (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_multithreading.htm), and wait for response, it takes around 15 sec to finish. Second, we process the response data, searching local mySQL DB, do some loop and calculation, and at the end save the result into the file system (the file location is a shared space using NFS), it takes around 10 sec to finish.

I use Linux 'top' command, found that when 1 job is running, it takes 100% cpu power sometimes. When I run 30 jobs at the same time, each jobs take <10% cpu power, I guess this is the reason why it takes 26 mins for each jobs...

Currently I have no idea how to improve the speed, to make it supports more users and the speed is ~30 sec...

We are using Rails 3.0.x, Ruby 1.9.2p290 (real threading?), a server running 4 VMs (DB, Ngnix, Ruby/Unicorn, Ruby/delayed_job).

What in my mind now is: 
- real threading (how to test if we are?)
- jRuby (it helps in this case?)
- Network IO (server admin said not likely)
- File System/NFS IO (server admin said not likely)

Anyone have similar experience can give me some idea, so I can dig in to the problem? Many Thanks!

Comment: Instead of opening 60 delayed_job workers, open 5 or so. You can pretty easily find the optimum number -- calculate the time per job and the number of workers that gives you the minimum is what you want. 10 every 3 minutes is better than 1 every 30 seconds but worse than 30 every 26 minutes. (And try to figure out why you need so much CPU time.)

Comment: I want to add to David's advice that you should [profile your application](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/examples/) to discover _why_ your searches are so intensive. OProfile is just one suggestion -- you might find more enlightening data by asking your SQL system to `EXPLAIN` its queries and adding indexing, removing locking, adding transactions, making smaller transactions, etc. Who knows. OProfile is a good mechanism of finding what is chewing your CPU though and will hopefully provide you with information you need to make the most improvement for least effort.

Comment: Thanks! I have more info on the hardware:
~2.4ghz, total 8 CPU (xeon x2) with HT so the VM can have 16 core

Comment: I puts some log with time in coding, with the 3rd party API request log, it shows that: file IO has no problem (almost instance); 3rd partyAPI call using threading is working (sending at the same second); 3rd party API response time is normal... Refer to my question, when 10 requests, the First part need ~90second, when 20 second is normal for waiting API response, but other 60 second is handling the response by the plugin, which is savon (http://savonrb.com/); The Second part use ~100 second...

Comment: Thanks Sarnold. We already used query_viewer to optimized the SQL, and we have memcached with >90% hit rate.

Now IMO, it looks like is the coding, including our coding, Rails itself, and plugin (like http://savonrb.com/), that running really slow when multi process running at the same time

Answer (score 1):

New Relic can give you a sense of where your jobs are spending their time. You can [set it up to monitor your jobs](http://newrelic.com/docs/ruby/monitoring-ruby-background-processes-and-daemons) and record a detailed trace of each one. There's a 14-day free trial that includes the detailed trace feature ("Transaction Traces").

The bottleneck could be in any of the areas you mention. If the DB is your bottleneck, you can tune your queries, possibly by adding indices. If your web requests are not really executing in parallel (not sure what your code looks like), you could use something like [typhoeus](https://github.com/dbalatero/typhoeus) to handle all the parallel business for you.

Savon is processing XML from the SOAP requests, so make sure you're using a faster XML library like libxml or nokogiri.

Comment: The system admin said "the server is ~2.4ghz, total 8 CPU (xeon x2) with HT so the VM can have 16 core"
I don't famous with server hardware and VM, so don't really know what does it means...
Ar yea, we are using CentOS 6.0 64bit